# How are multiple CPU Fetch Execute cycles synchronised?

Tags: assembly, concurrency, operating-system, hardware

TSET is the indivisible machine code instruction that does several things. Consider its logic as follows:

```
TSET(X)
if (x == 0) {
    x = 1;
    return true;
} else
    return false;
```

It is, according to classic OS text books, relied upon for thread synch. A semaphore implementation might use it. Because it is indivisible, it can be used to guard entry to a critical section even in the event of an untimely thread switch on the same CPU. Its use on a *single* CPU is well understood (by me) already.

Here's where my hardware knowledge is lacking: What if two competing threads on different CPUs issue the same TSET(x) "at the same time". This makes me ask if (and how) the fetch execute cycles of each CPU are *synchronised*. Is it that an instruction on CPU1 happens followed by an instruction on CPU2 then CPU1 again? Is this how it is done? Am I making sense? Have I answered my own question?

Answer (score 0):

This magic instruction is supposed to be atomic/indivisible, IOW, nothing should be able to alter `x` between the time it's compared with 0 and the time it's set to 1.

It's the whole point of it. If you read your books carefully, you will see examples of bad race conditions where similar code (read/comparison + modification) fails miserably because of inatomicity (is there such a word?).

Think of it yourself.

What would happen if this instruction wasn't atomic and 2 concurrent threads/processes executed in this order due to misfortunate scheduling?:

```
1: if (x==0)
2: if (x==0)
1: x=1, return true
2: x=1, return true
```

Both threads/processes would think they have gained exclusive access to some object that this lock variable `x` was guarding access to. Not good.

Comment: To expand slightly on the previous answer: 

The CPU:s will use cache synchronization protocols and memory barriers to ensure that this is the case.

A brief overview can be found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol